# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP (4)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have two servers, one is a webserver running apache and php, and the other is a database server with MySQL. The first uses the database of the second, 24 hours per day, 7 days per week.

The problem is which recently began to have mistakes sometimes daily, where the PHP apps show the message below:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP_DO_BANCO_DE_DADOS' (4)
```

We have some PHP applications in our webserver. One of these apps (legacy) which doesn't use any framework, and uses the PHP natively to connect to MySQL:

```
function AbreBD($mysqli = false) {

        global $conexao, $selecao, $conexao_mysqli;

        $servidor = '192.168.101.20:3306';
        $usuarioBD = 'user';
        $senhaBD = 'user';

        $conexao = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuarioBD, $senhaBD);
        $selecao = mysql_select_db("bioextratus", $conexao);

        if ($mysqli) {
            $conexao_mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuarioBD, $senhaBD, "bioextratus");
        }
}
```

Remembering that the code above is for a legacy application, and still uses the mysql driver instead of mysqli. Even in our most modern application with the codeigniter framework, this problem occurs.

I belive that the problem is the MySQL configuration or a network problem, despite the MySQL service are always available, as well the communication between the two servers.

The content of the file my.cnf of the MySQL server is (no comments):

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
skip-external-locking
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = false
open_files_limit        =       102400

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

key_buffer                      = 16M
key_buffer_size                 = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 256M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 8M
max_allowed_packet              = 16M
thread_stack                    = 196K
thread_cache_size               = 8
myisam-recover-options          = BACKUP
query_cache_limit               = 64M
query_cache_type                = 1
query_cache_size                = 256M
max_connections                 = 1024
max_user_connections            = 0
sort_buffer_size                = 2M

join_buffer_size                = 1M
tmp_table_size                  = 64M
max_heap_table_size             = 18M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 12M
```

Comment: You appear to have one of two problems (or possibly both). Either your database server is too busy, or your network connection between the web server and the database server is too busy. Either way, there's not enough data here to diagnose the problem. If this can be solved by programming, there's nothing here that will allow us to help. You need to profile your system and identify the bottlenecks. Only you can do that.

Comment: have you changed the config recently? or has the problem started with no changes?  are the servers in the same LAN or do you have other unknown variables introduced by hosting providers? We need more info.

Answer (score 1):

The AbreDB function is a tad suspect, for starters.

***IF*** the function is instructed to use MySQLI, it *makes a MySQL connection first anyway*.  There should be an if/else construct there to make sure that only one DB connection is made each time the function is called.  See also the "Singleton" suggestion below.

Given that this error is present, you should also check the application(s) for judicious use of mysql_close() or its equivalent --- it could be that as traffic increases, the MySQL server holds connections open until the timeout (which typically isn't too long, but might make a difference).  Applications should generally call a close() after using the database.

Depending on the nature of the app(s), you may want to use a permanent connection (mysql_pconnect() was the older version).  This is indicated if, for example, a call to a single web resource opens several connections to complete a page, which is a common error in many PHP programs that aren't really built with an eye to scaling.  Again, see the Singleton suggestion and try to make sure that scripts/apps use a common DB connection rather than opening them helter-skelter.

All that being said, there are some other things you might do to see if the problem can be alleviated:

- Try enabling MySQL's slow-queries log and see if there are queries
  that should be optimized/rewritten.
- Try increasing max_connections in my.cnf.
- Learn about the "Singleton" pattern and enforce use of it in your
  apps' database connector classes.